# How to set Okular as internal PDF viewer in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, 15.10, pdf, okular

How to make **Okular** the default PDF viewer in Chrome instead of **Chrome PDF Viewer**?

Here goes a few details related to my system:

```
martin@martinpc:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 47.0.2526.106 

martin@martinpc:~$ okular --version
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.13
Okular: 0.23.2

martin@martinpc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.10
Release: 15.10
Codename: wily
```

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/jeremysanders/okularplugin

Comment: Tried it just now, but the plugin won't show up in `Plugins` nor `Extensions` and PDFs are just downloaded after turning off the `Chrome PDF Viewer`. The installation was successful, I restarted browser and pc afterwards to no avail. I even changed the uid and gid of `/usr/lib/libokularplugin.so` and  `/opt/google/chrome/plugins` from root to myself, but nothing changed.